# Hash Validation in Webhook

Tags: java, python, security, hash

I am working on setting up an integration with a service called *Printify*. I am in the process of setting up webhooks and have one last step I am facing difficulty with: security with hash codes. The API documentation: https://developers.printify.com/#webhooks ---> *Securing your Webhooks*.

The flow is as follows:

1. Create a webhook via http api and pass an additional header *x-pfy-signature* with a secret key and a callable url that my system will listen to.
2. When a webhook event is invoked, that callable url will be invoked.
3. I should validate the request body using that secret key to ensure it is a legitimate invocation from *Printify*.

Step 3 is where I am having issues. They give an example code in Python:

```
import os
import hmac

def sha256hash(request):
    hash = hmac.new(os.environ['SECRET_TOKEN'].encode('utf-8'),
                    request.data.encode('utf-8'), 
                    'sha256')
    return 'sha256=' + hash.hexdigest()


def secure_compare(a, b):
    return hmac.compare_digest(a, b)


print('%r' % secure_compare(request.headers['x-pfy-signature'],
                            sha256hash(request)))
```

It appears that I am creating some encoded string by feeding in the request body received from *Printify* along with the secret key, then validating that the encoded string matches with the request header *x-pfy-signature,* which will be the same as the initial one I passed?

Can someone verify this is correct and outline how to do this with Node?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a NodeJS Solution: https://bytethisstore.com/articles/pg/printify-webhooks-node-js

The documentation is actually missing a step. When you create the secret key, you have to send it as a third parameter named 'secret' when you create the webhook. This is the part that's missing from the documentation.

So when you create the webhook, you send:

```
{
    "topic": "order:created",
    "url": "{webhook_callback_url}",
    "secret": "{secret_key}"
}
```

Then, whenever Printify sends data to your endpoint, they use that secret key to hash the response and send that hash as the x-pfy-signature header.

As in their python example, you have to compare hashes, not the secret key itself. You need to hash the data that was sent to the webhook with the secret key and then compare your hash to the signature that was sent. Just as you described.

In PHP this is much easier, and this is the function I use to check the signature:

```
function validate_webhook($request, $signature): bool
{
    $signature = str_replace('sha256=', '', $signature);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $request, {secret_key});
    return hash_equals($signature, $hash);
}
```

where `$request` is the body of the request, and `$signature` is the content of the x-pfy-signature header.